# Can't find docker-ce installation candidate on Kali Linux 2020.3

Tags: linux, docker, apt, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Docker Community Edition on my Kali Linux 2020.3, following tutorials such as: https://linuxhint.com/install_docker_kali_linux/

Although the repository is found during apt update:

```
OK:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease
OK:2 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/kali kali-rolling InRelease
```

No Installation candidate is found after running:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paket docker-ce ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.

E: Für Paket »docker-ce« existiert kein Installationskandidat. (No installation candidate for package "docker-ce" found, excuse the german here)
```

Does anybody know the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested the following script with a clean install of 64-bit Kali Linux 2020.3 and it works fine (the entire thing was run as root):

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
apt-get update
apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
apt-get -y install docker-ce
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

Is it possible you're using 32-bit version of Kali?

If so instead of:

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

you should do:

```
echo 'deb [arch=i386] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Edit:

I checked the [repository](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/stable/) and it seems there is no 32-bit Docker, so the above won't work.

Comment: Thank you, I indeed accidentally used a 32-bit version of Kali Linux, explaining even a lot more of the trouble I had during installation..